# android griview with image and text from database

Tags: android, database, image, gridview, textview

i have 1 app, that need the image and text into grid view...like this
[image]

but i am getting problem that i am displaying some data twice... i am not able to find the problem...
this is my logcat

```
02-09 06:31:41.191: W/FileUtils(4115): Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidgridviewexample/databases/Healing_Foods): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
02-09 06:31:41.231: I/System.out(4115): connected
02-09 06:31:41.281: I/System.out(4115): Black beans
02-09 06:31:41.281: I/System.out(4115): Dried peas
02-09 06:31:41.291: I/System.out(4115): Garbanzo beans
02-09 06:31:41.291: I/System.out(4115): Kidney beans
02-09 06:31:41.291: I/System.out(4115): Lentils
02-09 06:31:41.291: I/System.out(4115): Lima beans
02-09 06:31:41.291: I/System.out(4115): Miso
02-09 06:31:41.291: I/System.out(4115): Navy beans
02-09 06:31:41.291: I/System.out(4115): Pinto beans
02-09 06:31:41.291: I/System.out(4115): Soybeans
02-09 06:31:41.291: I/System.out(4115): Tofu And Tempeh
02-09 06:31:41.481: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:31:41.601: W/Resources(4115): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:31:41.601: I/System.out(4115): Black beansthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:31:41.711: D/dalvikvm(4115): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 78K, 5% free 3128K/3280K, paused 61ms, total 65ms
02-09 06:31:41.851: W/Resources(4115): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:31:41.861: I/System.out(4115): Dried peasthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:31:41.881: W/Resources(4115): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:31:41.881: I/System.out(4115): Garbanzo beansthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:31:41.891: W/Resources(4115): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:31:41.901: I/System.out(4115): Kidney beansthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:31:41.931: W/Resources(4115): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:31:41.931: I/System.out(4115): Lentilsthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:31:41.941: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 281 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:31:41.951: W/Resources(4115): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:31:41.961: I/System.out(4115): Black beansthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:31:42.011: D/gralloc_goldfish(4115): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-09 06:31:48.661: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 222 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:31:50.211: D/dalvikvm(4115): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 3% free 3551K/3656K, paused 46ms, total 53ms
02-09 06:31:50.281: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:31:51.411: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 133 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:31:52.231: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:31:52.381: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:31:53.171: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:31:53.291: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:31:53.361: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:31:53.571: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:31:54.111: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:31:54.251: I/Choreographer(4115): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:32:35.661: W/FileUtils(4361): Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidgridviewexample/databases/Healing_Foods): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
02-09 06:32:35.711: I/System.out(4361): connected
02-09 06:32:35.831: I/System.out(4361): Black beans
02-09 06:32:35.831: I/System.out(4361): Dried peas
02-09 06:32:35.831: I/System.out(4361): Garbanzo beans
02-09 06:32:35.841: I/System.out(4361): Kidney beans
02-09 06:32:35.841: I/System.out(4361): Lentils
02-09 06:32:35.841: I/System.out(4361): Lima beans
02-09 06:32:35.841: I/System.out(4361): Miso
02-09 06:32:35.841: I/System.out(4361): Navy beans
02-09 06:32:35.841: I/System.out(4361): Pinto beans
02-09 06:32:35.841: I/System.out(4361): Soybeans
02-09 06:32:35.841: I/System.out(4361): Tofu And Tempeh
02-09 06:32:36.231: W/Resources(4361): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:32:36.261: I/System.out(4361): Black beansthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:32:36.461: D/dalvikvm(4361): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 82K, 5% free 3128K/3280K, paused 118ms, total 133ms
02-09 06:32:36.811: W/Resources(4361): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:32:36.811: I/System.out(4361): Dried peasthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:32:36.931: W/Resources(4361): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:32:36.931: I/System.out(4361): Garbanzo beansthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:32:37.001: W/Resources(4361): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:32:37.001: I/System.out(4361): Kidney beansthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:32:37.041: W/Resources(4361): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:32:37.041: I/System.out(4361): Lentilsthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:32:37.061: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 647 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:32:37.081: W/Resources(4361): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:32:37.081: I/System.out(4361): Black beansthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:32:37.161: D/gralloc_goldfish(4361): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-09 06:32:37.901: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 330 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:32:38.331: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:20.161: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:20.731: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 216 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:22.081: D/dalvikvm(4361): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 21K, 3% free 3551K/3656K, paused 64ms, total 68ms
02-09 06:33:22.111: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 169 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:22.461: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:22.931: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:23.131: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:23.241: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:23.491: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:23.611: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:24.261: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:25.031: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:27.861: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:28.521: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:28.621: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:28.721: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:28.831: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:28.981: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:29.421: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:29.591: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:30.161: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:33:30.301: I/Choreographer(4361): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:35:00.891: W/FileUtils(4986): Failed to chmod(/data/data/com.javacodegeeks.android.androidgridviewexample/databases/Healing_Foods): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
02-09 06:35:00.941: I/System.out(4986): connected
02-09 06:35:01.051: I/System.out(4986): Black beans
02-09 06:35:01.051: I/System.out(4986): Dried peas
02-09 06:35:01.061: I/System.out(4986): Garbanzo beans
02-09 06:35:01.061: I/System.out(4986): Kidney beans
02-09 06:35:01.061: I/System.out(4986): Lentils
02-09 06:35:01.061: I/System.out(4986): Lima beans
02-09 06:35:01.061: I/System.out(4986): Miso
02-09 06:35:01.061: I/System.out(4986): Navy beans
02-09 06:35:01.061: I/System.out(4986): Pinto beans
02-09 06:35:01.061: I/System.out(4986): Soybeans
02-09 06:35:01.061: I/System.out(4986): Tofu And Tempeh
02-09 06:35:01.091: I/System.out(4986): 11
02-09 06:35:01.091: I/System.out(4986): 11
02-09 06:35:01.461: I/System.out(4986): 11
02-09 06:35:01.591: D/dalvikvm(4986): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 84K, 5% free 3126K/3280K, paused 72ms, total 83ms
02-09 06:35:01.591: W/Resources(4986): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:35:01.631: I/System.out(4986): Black beansthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:35:01.961: W/Resources(4986): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:35:01.981: I/System.out(4986): Dried peasthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:35:02.001: W/Resources(4986): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:35:02.031: I/System.out(4986): Garbanzo beansthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:35:02.111: W/Resources(4986): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:35:02.111: I/System.out(4986): Kidney beansthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:35:02.221: W/Resources(4986): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:35:02.221: I/System.out(4986): Lentilsthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:35:02.231: I/Choreographer(4986): Skipped 570 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:35:02.371: I/System.out(4986): 11
02-09 06:35:02.391: W/Resources(4986): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
02-09 06:35:02.391: I/System.out(4986): Black beansthis is mobile data 
02-09 06:35:02.461: D/gralloc_goldfish(4986): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-09 06:35:02.801: I/Choreographer(4986): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-09 06:35:02.811: I/System.out(4986): 11
02-09 06:38:00.921: I/System.out(4986): 11
02-09 06:38:01.211: I/Choreographer(4986): Skipped 183 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

And the code:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.androidgridviewexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] countries;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] countries) {
        this.context = context;
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.countries, null);

            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.label);

            textView.setText(countries[position]);

            ImageView flag = (ImageView) gridView .findViewById(R.id.flag);

            String mobile = countries[position];
System.out.println(mobile+"this is mobile data ");
            if (mobile.equals("abc")) {
                flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.greekflag);
            } else if (mobile.equals("xyz")) {
                flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.germanflag);
            } else if (mobile.equals("ab")) {
                flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.italianflag);
            } 


            else {
                flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.britishflag);
            }




        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        System.out.println(countries.length);
        return countries.length;
    }


@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `getView` method you are only setting the text and image when your first create the view - when `convertView` is null.

You need to create a ViewHolder class and attach it to the view with `setTag`. Then you can set the text and the image both when the view is created and when it is re-used.

A good example of use of the ViewHolder pattern is [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html).